# Need more if statments in calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, calculated-column

I have a problem with calculated formula, this take the information from a choice column. 
The problem is that i have 23 choices, and the calculated column only permit 20. When i add the 21 if, it marks me an error. 
When we have an error with customer we create a ticket, wich have 23 options (choice column) but its transform to 7 departments (Calculated column).

There's another way?

Comment: Is it possible to club multiple IF statements? Can you show us your calculated column formula?

Comment: My formula its to long to post here but i give u a resume:

Comment: FIRST PART =IF(Causa="CANCELACION DE FACTURA POR FALTA DE SEGUIMIENTO AL PORTAL";"Cobranza";IF(Causa="CHOFER NO ENTREGO FACTURA A REVISION";"Chofer";IF(Causa="CLIENTE COMETE ERROR";"Ventas";IF(Causa="CLIENTE NO FIRMA Y SELLA FACTURA DE RECIBIDO";"Chofer";IF(Causa="CLIENTE SOLICITA CAMBIO DE MERCANCIA";"Ventas";IF(Causa="CLIENTE SOLICITA REFACTURACION";"Ventas";IF(Causa="DATOS INCORRECTOS DE FACTURACION";"Ventas";IF(Causa="DIFERENCIAS EN PRECIOS";"Ventas";IF(Causa="ERROR EN ELABORACION DE PEDIDO Y/O FACTURA";"Ventas";IF(Causa="ERROR EN ENTREGA A CLIENTE";"Chofer"

Comment: SECOND PART ;IF(Causa="ERROR EN RECEPCION Y CARGA DE PEDIDOS";"Chofer";IF(Causa="ERROR EN SURTIMIENTO";"Almacen";IF(Causa="FACTURA NO SE ENVIA A REVISION POR QUEDARSE EN OFICINA";"Administracion";IF(Causa="MERCANCIA DAÑADA POR ACOMODO Y/O MANEJO INADECUADO";"Chofer";IF(Causa="NO ENTREGO FACTURA A REVISION";"Chofer";IF(Causa="NO SE ENTREGO PEDIDO AL CLIENTE";"Chofer";IF(Causa="PEDIDO SIN EXISTENCIA FISICA Y CON EXISTENCIA EN SISTEMA";"Inventarios";IF(Causa="PRODUCTO DAÑADO DE FABRICA";"Proveedor";IF(Causa="PRODUCTO QUIMICO CON DEFICIENCIAS";"Produccion"

Comment: THIRD PART ;IF(Causa="PRODUCTO SURTIDO EN MAL ESTADO";"Almacen"))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: What im doing is: the first column where i have the chioces, i create 2 calculated Column, then, another calculated column brings both list.